Will the amoeba population die out? Murphy's law
This problem has been asked here multiple times.
Suppose you have one Amoeba and it has some probability of dying, some probability of multiplying by 2 and some probability of multiplying by 3. All following amoebas if they exist have the same probabilities.
Now, I understand the solutions solved with recursion, the maths does make sense to some degree, but logically, they don't make sense to me, since at no point does the chance of the amoeba population dying out go to 0 no matter how much they multiply (it just becomes very unlikely), doesn't this go against murphy's law?
I expected them to, on a long enough timeframe, always die no matter what, since any event with a strictly positive probability is supposed to come true after a big enough number of tries.

You're expecting far too much here from "Murphy's Law". It couldn't possibly be the case that for every sequence of events each of positive probability, the union of them occurs with probability $1$.
Instead, "Murphy's Law" says something like the following: if you have a sequence of independent events with the same probability, then the union occurs with probability $1$.
In your example, let $A_n$ be the event that the population dies out at generation $n$. The events $A_n$ are not independent, and they don't have the same probability.
By considering some other simple examples you can get some intuition why the conditions are needed.
For example, take a random variable $X$ with, say, geometric distribution. Consider the sequence of events $\{X=1\}$, $\{X=3\}$, $\{X=5\}, \dots$ . All of these events have positive probability. But it is not the case that with probability $1$, at least one of them occurs. There is also positive probability that $X$ takes an even value, in which case none of the events in the sequence hold.
For an even more trivial example, consider the case where all the events in your sequence are literally the same event. That is, let $A$ be an event with $P(A)=p\in(0,1)$, and consider the sequence $A, A, A, A, \dots$. All elements of the sequence have positive probability. Either every event in the sequence occurs (this happens with probability $p$), or no event in the sequence occurs (this happens with probability $1-p$).
A more general result is the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma. If you have a sequence of independent events, and the sum of their probabilities is infinite, then with probability $1$, infinitely many of them occur.
